# Compare two fields in same document without using script elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

We are using elastic version 7.10.2. I want to compare two fields from a same document.Scripting is disabled in my organization.
Kindly help in building below query without using script.
Here my query is : nickname is null or nickname is empty or nickname is equal to firstname.

Hard part is how to build query to get the records which have nickname is equal to firstname

Relevant script query to be converted to normal query :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [{
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "inline": "doc['nickname.keyword'].value==null || doc['nickname.keyword'].value =='' || doc['nickname.keyword'].value == doc['firstname.keyword'].value",
            "lang": "painless",
            
          }
        } 
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are already comparing the `nickname.keyword` to your `firstname` also mentioned this is the hard part, for this why you need a script, you can simply use the search query on this keyword field and get the result you want.

You can use below [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) for it.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "nickname.keyword": {
        "value": "your-nickname", // provide your nickname as value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @sardarCoder yeah pls tell me :)

Comment: Hi  @Opster Elasticsearch Ninja  , I don't have input stringto compare I just want records which have nickname and firstname as same and I dont want to use script any alternative to above script